# In an Orchard site, can the output cache be preserved during module updates?

Tags: orchardcms, outputcache

The site has over 7,000 pages of content. When most of the pages are cached the site handle its traffic acceptably. When, for example, a code update is deployed for a module, the cache is flushed. (This could also happen from some other event, like a server restart or the app pool getting recycled.)

The site is getting hit by a search engine spider, which does its job of re-indexing the site, checking on all the pages it knows of, and triggering the process of rebuilding the cache for all pages. This is pegging the CPU at 90% to 98% and causing the site to respond slow for all page requests.

Is there a way to preserve what is in the output cache through a rebuild or restart?

Comment: You're caching in memory?

Comment: We're using the output cache module, which, as I understand, uses memory as the cache data store.

Comment: @JonH Yes, by default. But the underlying storage can be switched to something else (like Redis or something custom made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, although it requires you to use an external cache server like [`Redis`](http://redis.io/). The default cache provider uses the in-memory storage, which will always be reset when the app pool gets restarted. The latest Orchard release supports Redis out of the box via `Orchard.Redis` core module.

The above applies to both business cache (`ICacheService`) as well as output caching.

Comment: I've taken a look at the Redis module, and now I'm worse off than before...please explain "out of the box". Here's my problem now: enabling the Redis cache module breaks the Orchard site, and there is no way to disable the module nor figure out what configuration settings are required. There is no substantial documentation on either the Contrib.Cache.Memcached or Contrib.Cache.Redis modules - they have broken links in the module gallery.

Comment: @JonH I didn't mean Contrib.Cache.Redis module, but the one that comes with the core (hence "out of the box"), ie. Orchard.Redis. Updated the answer to make it clear. If you're using Orchard 1.9 then you already have it as it was introduced then. If not - something's not right with your codebase or you must have removed this module at some point.

Comment: Crystal clear answer now - thank you! As it turned out, doing a proof of concept was fairly simple. I installed Redis locally using an MSI file on the MSOpenTech redis GitHub release page. I added a Orchard.Redis.OutputCache connection string to the web.config. I enabled the Redis and Redis Output Cache modules in Orchard. I was then able to see loaded pages in the Redis database using Redis Desktop Manager and in the cache stats in Orchard. Recycling the app pool or restarting the site did not evict anything from cache, so I'm pleased! Now: getting the cache proactively populated...